# Python exceptions and regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, search

I have an expression which I'm using to raise exceptions in the code, except one case where this expression is allowed:

```
searchexp = re.search( r'^exp1=.*, exp2=(.*),.*', line )
```

I want to raise an exception whenever this condition is hit except one case when I want it to print a warning

```
elif searchexp: 
  if searchexp.group(1) == 'tag'): 
    print("-w- just a warning that its a tag")
  else:
    raise Exception("-E- This is illegal to do")
```

In simple English

```
if (searchexp)
  raise an Exception except if searchexp.group(1) == 'tag'
```

How do I do this in python?

Comment: The code you have looks reasonable ... Can you post a simple self-contained example that demonstrates the behavior that you are having trouble with?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way. Wrap every `re.search()` with `wrap_search()`. Which will check the returned match.

```
import warnings

def wrap_search(match):
    if not match:
        return

    if match.group(1) == "tag":
        warnings.warn("-w- just a warning that its a tag")
    else:
        raise Exception("-E- This is illegal to do")

    return match

searchexp = wrap_search(re.search( r'^exp1=.*, exp2=(.*),.*', line ))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can  define this Warning with `Warning`clause and not an `Exception` one, so you can raise a `Warning` and catch it later, and then use it as you want.

example:

```
try:
    try:
        # this code is supposed to fail with warning
    except Exception, e:
        raise Warning('my warning is here: {e}'.format(e=str(e))
    try:
        # this is another code supposed to fail with exception
    except Exception, e:
        raise 
except Warning, e:
    print ('My Warning was '+ str(e))
except Exception:
    raise Exception('write your exception here')
```

And off course, you can define lots of exceptions in python and write some of your own.

Comment: Way too nested and cluttered.

Answer (score 0):

Use assertions

Your code becomes

```
assert searchexp.group(1) == 'tag', "-E- This is illegal to do"
```

See https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=assert#grammar-token-assert_stmt

Comment: Though this is effective, effective, assertions are mostly supposed to be used for debugging (e.g. test if a value is has come out a certain way at a point in running the program), not actual error-throwing.

Comment: You are right, as they can be disabled.   Although the OP did not specify if it was for debugging or not, the code seems to validate user input.  Assertions would not be the best choice.

Comment: Also I want the opposite- assert an exception in all cases except when searchexp.group(1) == 'tag'. How will that work?

Comment: The exception will occur when the condition is **False**, so this example will raise an exception for all values except 'tag'.  (But if you want to invert it, just change `==` for  `!=`).